# MySQL finding the average of a count() of rows

Tags: mysql, count, average

I'm trying to find a way to modify this query:

```
SELECT work_order_number, COUNT(1) 
FROM tmanagerprod.work_order_detail 
where client_id = 'x' and transaction_type = 'y'
group by work_order_number;
```

The query returns a count of the number of records where work_order_number = 'x' and I need the average of that count. I've tried various iterations of the avg() function, trying to average the COUNT(1) but so far it's resulted in a string of errors.  I have also reviewed similar questions on here but they all seem to be average data values not row counts and the suggestions have not worked for me.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here as you can interpret this question/SQL on multiple ways.. See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a subquery.

```
SELECT AVG(count)
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM work_order_detail
    WHERE client_id = 'x' and transaction_type = 'y'
    group by work_order_number) AS x
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked brilliantly, and thank you for the super fast response!